# Check for doubles in bookkeeper

Tags: python, histogram

Still being new to Python, I had to create a function that checks for doubles and if doubles are found it should return 'has duplicates'. So I have already finished the code correctly, but I'm more confused about why it originally found "bookkeeper" to have no duplicates with the code below.

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d

def has_duplicates(string):
    x = histogram(string)
    for b, c in x.items():
        if c > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

for string in test_dups:
    if has_duplicates(string):
        print(string, "has duplicates")
    else:
        print(string, "has no duplicates")
```

**Output:**

```
zzz has duplicates
dog has no duplicates
bookkeeper has no duplicates
subdermatoglyphic has no duplicates
subdermatoglyphics has duplicates
```

This is what I changed to make it work. But I would really like to understand why 'bookkeeper' didn't test correctly.

```
def has_duplicates(string):
    x = histogram(string)
    for b, c in x.items():
        if c > 1:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: It effectively only tests for duplicates for the first letter in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your `has_duplicates` function returns too soon. Take a look at this for-loop:

```
for b, c in x.items():
        if c > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Assuming that `x` is not empty, this for-loop will only have one iteration. This is so, because you only ask the question `c > 1` once, and then immediately return either `True` or `False`, terminating the for-loop and the function prematurely. Basically, this has the effect of only checking for doubles for the first key-value pair in the dictionary `x`.

You want to give the for-loop a chance to ask the same question for all key-value pairs. Of course, once you find one key-value pair which has a value greater than one, you have an "early-out", and don't need to look at the rest of the key-value pairs.